# Strange result while using Javascript not operator

Tags: javascript, syntax, bit-manipulation

Before anyone jumps in to answer and bash me for asking a silly question; I'm aware of what the not operator does, at least in other languages it should invert a result from true to false and vice versa. The thing I'm stuck on is the strange behavior I get from time to time. I.e. I had this in my code. It's not doing what I expect it to do.

```
_checkOnOff: function(inst) {
    return (!$.suggestBox.onOff || !$.suggestBox._get(inst, 'onOff')) ?  false : true;
},
```

The actual values for the 'onOff' variables that I'm dealing with here are 0 and 1. I'm assuming that the '!' operator will reverse them.

However I couldn't get it to work until I changed the function to explicitly state '== 0' like so...

```
_checkOnOff: function(inst) {
    return ($.suggestBox.onOff == 0 || $.suggestBox._get(inst, 'onOff') == 0) ?  false : true;
},
```

**Edit: Added info** Both $.suggestBox.onOff and $.suggestBox._get(inst, 'onOff') will be either 0 or 1.

My question is why didn't !$.suggestBox.onOff produce true when $.suggestBox.onOff was equal to 0? Is Javascript ! equivalant to the bitwise operator?

**Edit: Second attempt**

I tried using '!!' like was suggested (to get a bool) and found nothing changed. Here is the code and outputs:

```
        console.log('val: ' + $.suggestBox.onOff);  // outputs: 0
        console.log('! : ' + !$.suggestBox.onOff);  // outputs: false
        console.log('!! : ' + !!$.suggestBox.onOff);   //outputs: true
        console.log('!!! : ' + !!!$.suggestBox.onOff);   //outputs: false
```

The output doesn't change if $.suggestBox.onOff is 1 or 0!!! it's still false, true, false. What is going on?!

**Edit: Third attempt** I found out that it has something to do with my variable. I don't know how, but it has to do with the way that it has been set. Ok, prepare yourselves, what I'm about to tell you, may very well blow your mind and change the way you type on the keyboard. It's that incredible:

```
        //this.onOff = 0;
        console.log('this.onOff: ' + this.onOff);   //output: 0
        console.log('! : ' + ! this.onOff);  //output: false
        console.log('!! : ' + !! this.onOff);   //output: true
```

If I uncomment out the 'this.onOff = 0', thereby explicitly assigning this.onOff to a literal, it changes the output to:

- 0
- true
- false

I just found out why. I will write it down in the answer section. Small clue is that it's the way the variable $.suggestBox.onOff was set.

Comment: I've seen people use `!!` to force an int/string to behave as a bool. Sounds mad but try `!!!`

Comment: Does `_get()` return a string?

Comment: Aside: `(!x || !y) ? false : true` is equivalent to `!(!x || !y)`, and distributing the `!` via [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) yields `x && y`. Much simpler!

Comment: @popnoodles There's no need for `!!!`. Just `!` would do the job

Comment: @JohnKugelman - In JavaScript, `x && y` does not return a Boolean; rather, the first truthy value is returned. Since the OP wants a Boolean, it should be cast as such: `!! (x && y)`.

Comment: @MarkLinus according to OP, apparently not

Comment: @popnoodles I know, but it makes no sense to me

Comment: @MarkLinus It makes no sense to me either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `$.suggestBox.onOff` is set with `"0"` as a string, which in JavaScript is always truthy.

Since `"0"` is truthy and `0` is falsy, you'd expect `0 == "0"` to be false, but it's not.

Try the following in your console:

```
!! "0"; // true
!! 0; // false
0 == "0"; // true
```

Weird? Yes. Welcome to the awkward world of JavaScript!

---

To get around this issue, you should either have `$.suggestBox.onOff` be an actual number, or convert it on the fly:

```
_checkOnOff: function(inst) {
    return !! ( +$.suggestBox.onOff && +$.suggestBox._get(inst, 'onOff') );
}
```

---

**Update**: Since you pointed out in the comments that you're setting it by a text value, use this when setting it so that it's always set as a number:

```
$.suggestBox.onOff = +$(this).val();
```

Comment: Hah I was just going to write this! Beat me to it. You've got it! It's becuase $.suggestBox.onOff was declared by `$.suggestBox.onOff = $(this).val()` I fixed it by changing it to  `$.suggestBox.onOff = Number($(this).val())` . Good show though! By the way, can you explain why you put the plus sign infront of the variables? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd - The `+` is a shortcut to `Number`. Just set it initially like that, and all your troubles will go away: `$.suggestBox.onOff = +$(this).val()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused, because you're negating a string, not a number.  Strings are a bit different and handled a bit funny when it comes to their evaluation as a boolean.

```
!0
```

is true, as expected.

```
!"0"
```

is false... so, the question, is "0" *truthy*?

I wish I had a better source (sitepoint isn't bad, but it's not as authoritative as a w3 document), but, according to http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

> The following values are always falsy:
>
> false
>
> 0 (zero)
>
> "" (empty string)
>
> null
>
> undefined 
>   NaN (a special Number value meaning Not-a-Number!)
>
> All other values are truthy, including
>   "0" (zero in quotes), "false" (false in quotes), empty functions,
>   empty arrays, and empty objects.

So, what you are seeing is indeed expected.